# How to get Dispart details(diskname (ex : Disk 0) free & usage of disk) using Golang package

Tags: go

How to get Dispart details(disk name (ex: Disk 0) free & usage of the disk) using Golang package

Comment: Sorry, Diskpart**** details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this package `github.com/shirou/gopsutil` for `diskpart` details:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/disk"
)

func main() {
    diskInfo, err := disk.Usage("/")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(diskInfo)
}
```

Comment: No. Do you need for winodws?

Comment: I have to run the above code, not working in the Windows environment.

Comment: Yes, Fahim. I need for windows.

Comment: The above package only returns drive details only. I need for disk details.

Comment: Example: "Diskpart" command execute in command prompt. and then "list disk" command executes.(Same result I need for Golang package)

Comment: I need for Golang package only.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rely on any package of golang, You can just run OS(Window's) commands from Golang.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("diskpart")
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(cmd)
    cmd2 := exec.Command("list disk")
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(cmd2)
}
```

Comment: is that work on the French language? because of the above code run in the french language environment.

Comment: It will work, I never used Windows since 2005 but you need to test code first.

Comment: Worked!!!.but it will return the french language. How can I read the data?